# does lldb automatically load new shared libs when they are updated

Tags: emacs, lldb

I am not sure if this is because lldb does not use the new shared libs. What happened is

1) I used a lldb in emacs to debug a code

2) updated the shared libs the code needs

3) re-run the program debugged by lldb.

The code run and stopped at some random location. The problem was resolved if I killed the debug session in emacs, and opened a new one. I never have the same issue with gdb.

This also happens when switching between optimized and debug code. The steps are like
1) lldb an optimized program
2) build the program in debug mode
3) rerun the program in lldb. lldb does not use the new debug code.

Comment: Should do, please file a bug if this isn't working.

Comment: @JimIngham The problem happened again. I use lldb to debug a program that loads a shared lib A. I put breakpoints in A, run the program. It does not stop. Then I recalled that A is not a debug build. So I rebuilt A with -g, run the program in lldb again. It does not stop. Kill lldb in emacs, start a new lldb. It works. I am not sure if I can reproduce the issue with a small code...

Comment: So one possibility you are on macOS and if you are just rebuilding with -g is that lldb uses the UUID's of binaries to identify them.  I think it's possible that a no-code change like just rebuilding with -g won't change the UUID, so we won't think we have to reread it.  If you are on OS X you can use `dwarfdump --uuid` to print the UUID of a binary.  If you see this, can you check whether the UUID of the new binary and the one for the wrong binary (which lldb tells you about in the output of `image list`) are the same?

Comment: @JimIngham I am on Linux REHL6.5 64bit. Could the same thing happen?

Comment: I'm actually not that familiar with how this part of lldb works on Linux.  Might ask on the lldb-dev list, the info about that is here: http://lists.llvm.org/mailman/listinfo/lldb-dev  Most of the people who work on lldb for Linux hang out there.